# How do I copy the directory structure into the text of a file?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, substitute, filesystem

This might be more of a bash question than vim, but I thought I should start here. Frequently when editing code, it would be "nice" to copy and paste the directory structure into a text editor. For example:

I have the following directory structure:

```
img/foo.jpg
img/foo2.jpg
img/Another_foo.jpg
```

I'm editing a file with the following code:

```
<img src="img/foo.jpg">
<img src="img/foo2.jpg">
<img src="img/Another_foo.jpg">
```

I add more files to the img directory so that it looks like this:

```
img/foo.jpg
img/foo2.jpg
img/Another_foo.jpg
img/bar.gif
img/bar2.jpg
img/Another_bar.png
```

In graphical editing environments, I would just copy and paste the filenames into the file and quickly get this:

```
<img src="img/foo.jpg">
<img src="img/foo2.jpg">
<img src="img/Another_foo.jpg">
<img src="img/bar.gif">
<img src="img/bar2.jpg">
<img src="img/Another_bar.png">
```

(For larger filesets, I hack my way through by pasting the directory structure into Excel and then concatenating the code for each line).

Is there an easily-reproducible way to do something similar with vim?

Answer (score 5):

First step, insert the file listing:

```
:r!ls
```

Second step, turn each line into an HTML tag:

```
:'[,s/.*/<img src="&">
```

See `:help :r`, `:help range`, `:help mark-motions`, and `:help :s`.

Comment: You can use `:r!find some_dir -type f` for a recursive listing (you can optionally add `-maxdepth` to only find files up to a certain depth).

Comment: As a side note, if you're not into substitutions, you could mark your filenames in vim in blockwise visual mode (<Ctrl>-v), and then type `I<img src=` to insert at the beginning of all lines. This does not work properly for `A` (it will fill up with whitespaces), but you could use `gv` to reselect, then type `:'<,'> normal A">` to append "> to all lines (you could have done it that way in the first step, using `normal I` instead of `normal A`).

Comment: In addition to @PhilippFrank 's comment, you can append to the end of every line by selecting the region and calling `:right`, followed by blockwise selection and `A">`. The answer is much nicer though